# How do you implement Pipes and Filters pattern with LinqToSQL/Entity Framework/NHibernate?

Tags: linq-to-sql, design-patterns, linq-to-entities, pipes-filters

While building by DAL Repository, I stumbled upon a concept called Pipes and Filters. I read about it [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/05/Pipes-and-filters-The-IEnumerable-appraoch.aspx), here and saw a screencast from [here](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvcstore-part-3/). I am still not sure how to go about implementing this pattern. Theoretically all sounds good , but how do we really implement this in an enterprise scenario?

I will appreciate, if you have any resources,tips or examples ro explanation for this pattern in context to the data mappers/ORM mentioned in the question.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please add a comment if you decide to downvote the question for any reason.

Comment: Something wrong with the question??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ultimately, LINQ on `IEnumerable<T>` *is* a pipes and filters implementation. `IEnumerable<T>` is a *streaming* API - meaning that data is lazily returns as you ask for  it (via iterator blocks), rather than loading everything at once, and returning a big buffer of records.

This means that your query:

```
var qry = from row in source // IEnumerable<T>
          where row.Foo == "abc"
          select new {row.ID, row.Name};
```

is:

```
var qry = source.Where(row => row.Foo == "abc")
            .Select(row = > new {row.ID, row.Name});
```

as you enumerate over this, it will consume the data lazily. You can see this graphically with Jon Skeet's [Visual LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/02/20/visual-linq-watch-query-expressions-as-they-happen.aspx). The only things that break the pipe are things that force buffering; `OrderBy`, `GroupBy`, etc. For high volume work, Jon and myself worked on [Push LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/04/quot-push-quot-linq-revisited-next-attempt-at-an-explanation.aspx) for doing aggregates without buffering in such scenarios.

`IQueryable<T>` (exposed by most ORM tools - LINQ-to-SQL, Entity Framework, LINQ-to-NHibernate) is a slightly different beast; because the database engine is going to do most of the heavy lifting, the chances are that most of the steps are already done - all that is left is to consume an `IDataReader` and project this to objects/values - but that is still typically a pipe (`IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`) unless you call `.ToArray()`, `.ToList()` etc.

With regard to use in enterprise... [my view](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/pragmatic-linq.html) is that it is fine to use `IQueryable<T>` to write composable queries inside the repository, but they shouldn't *leave* the repository - as that would make the internal operation of the repository subject to the caller, so you would be unable to properly unit test / profile / optimize / etc. I've taken to doing clever things in the repository, but return lists/arrays. This also means my repository stays unaware of the implementation.

This is a shame - as the temptation to "return" `IQueryable<T>` from a repository method is quite large; for example, this would allow the caller to add paging/filters/etc - but remember that they haven't actually consumed the data yet. This makes resource management a pain. Also, in MVC etc you'd need to ensure that the *controller* calls `.ToList()` or similar, so that it isn't the view that is controlling data access (otherwise, again, you can't unit test the controller properly).

A *safe* (IMO) use of filters in the DAL would be things like:

```
public Customer[] List(string name, string countryCode) {
     using(var ctx = new CustomerDataContext()) {
         IQueryable<Customer> qry = ctx.Customers.Where(x=>x.IsOpen);
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) {
             qry = qry.Where(cust => cust.Name.Contains(name));
         }
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryCode)) {
             qry = qry.Where(cust => cust.CountryCode == countryCode);
         }
         return qry.ToArray();
     }
}
```

Here we've added filters on-the-fly, but nothing happens until we call `ToArray`. At this point, the data is obtained and returned (disposing the data-context in the process). This can be fully unit tested. If we did something similar but just returned `IQueryable<T>`, the caller might do something like:

```
 var custs = customerRepository.GetCustomers()
       .Where(x=>SomeUnmappedFunction(x));
```

And all of a sudden our DAL starts failing (cannot translate `SomeUnmappedFunction` to TSQL, etc). You can still do a *lot* of interesting things in the repository, though.

The only pain point here is that it might push you to have a few overloads to support different calling patterns (with/without paging, etc). Until [optional/named parameters](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/immutability-and-optional-parameters.html) arrives, I find the best answer here is to use extension methods on the interface; that way, I only need one concrete repository implementation:

```
class CustomerRepository {
    public Customer[] List(
        string name, string countryCode,
        int? pageSize, int? pageNumber) {...}
}
interface ICustomerRepository {
    Customer[] List(
        string name, string countryCode,
        int? pageSize, int? pageNumber);
}
static class CustomerRepositoryExtensions {
    public static Customer[] List(
          this ICustomerRepository repo,
          string name, string countryCode) {
       return repo.List(name, countryCode, null, null); 
    }
}
```

Now we have virtual overloads (as extension methods) on `ICustomerRepository` - so our caller can use `repo.List("abc","def")` without having to specify the paging.

---

Finally - without LINQ, using pipes and filters becomes a lot more painful. You'll be writing some kind of text based query (TSQL, ESQL, HQL). You can obviously append strings, but it isn't very "pipe/filter"-ish. The "Criteria API" is a bit better - but not as elegant as LINQ.