# allowing client to filter by multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I've got an MVC solution that exposes data from a database.

They issue an HttpGet and my controller provides the data to the client:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{someGuid:guid}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Guid? someGuid)
{
    var responseData = _someService.RecordSet.Where(x=>x.guid == someGuid);

    return Request.ResponseMessageFromApiEntity(responseData);
}
```

**How would I implement a way for the client to be able to issue a request with multiple combinations of parameters?** They could pass in 2 or 5 or up to 10, and I would need to filter the dataset by those parameters.

Comment: I have multiple get endpoints.  The controlers are smart enought to figure out which one is being used. Something like this: www.YourURL/api/controller?var1=value&var1=value
public IHttpActionResult Get(string var1, string var2)

Comment: what if they decide to just pass in Honda?

Comment: try this article. http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-api-catch-all-route-parameter-binding.  It just sets a deliminator to split the parameters on.  I am using mostly web api so I would just stick an object into the http request body.

Comment: You mean pass multiple guids?  Just declare it as an array as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api).  Or do you mean different parameter names?  Just add them as nullable parms to the method and use `Where` chaining.

Comment: @stephen.vakil i need multiple parameters, what if the client passes in an empty parameter, how would my Where work? how would i chain the where's in a conditional fashion (conditional based upon whether a parameter was provided or not)

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the [Pipes and Filters Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679027/how-do-you-implement-pipes-and-filters-pattern-with-linqtosql-entity-framework-n)

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{someGuid:guid}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Guid? someGuid, [FromUri] int someInt)
{
    var responseData = _someService.RecordSet.AsQueryable(); // or some base query or equivalent
    if (someGuid.HasValue)
    {
       responseData = responseData.Where(x=>x.guid == someGuid);
    }

    if (someInt.HasValue)
    {
       responseData = responseData.Where(x=>x.int == someInt);
    }

    return Request.ResponseMessageFromApiEntity(responseData);
}
```