# Best practice to implement static Method

Tags: c#, methods, static

I am trying to implement a static function in my Product class to "Get" products.

The outcome I got to work is to nest a Get subclass like this:

```
Product.Get.ByName("Cool Product")
```

But I am feeling a subclass ist not the best practice for this.

I would like to accomplish it like this what i think would be right implementation:

```
Product.Get().ByName(x => x.Name = "Cool Product");
```

How could I create this kind of sub sub method(is this even the right word?)?

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to do.  Do you want to do something like the [pipes and filters pattern described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679027/how-do-you-implement-pipes-and-filters-pattern-with-linqtosql-entity-framework-n)?

Comment: @stephen.vakil yes this looks like what I am thinking I want to accomplish. For example when you call a mehtod that returns a List u can directly use this List with like List.foreach()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add `.` after get, you will need a subclass however you can make this subclass itself static:

```
class Product
{
     public static class Get
     {
          public static Product ByName()
          {
                //some code to return a product (or may be products)
          }
     }
}
```

Now it can be accessed like:

```
Product.Get.ByName();
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8J2bRZ)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am doing right now but I am not sure if this is right way.

Comment: @josef_skywalker if you want to gather all **Get** methods together, ById, By...., Yes its the right way to do it.

Comment: Guess you are right and I am confusing about actual getting of objects and filtering the objects after i get them

Comment: @josef_skywalker glad if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a Get class, is this simpler:

```
    public class Product
    {
        public static Product GetByName()
        {
            //some code to return a product (or maybe products)
        }
    }
```

Usage: `Product.GetByName();`